# How do I share resources in a relational-database (specific case)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have a table Dogs

```
mysql> select * from dogs;
+----------+-------------+----------+
| dog_id   | tail_length | owner_id |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| dog-id-1 | 1 cm        | owner-1  |
| dog-id-2 | 2 cm        | owner-2  |
| dog-id-3 | 3 cm        | owner-3  |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Where *dog_id* is a primary key and *owner_id* is unique.
Now I want sharing of dogs to be possible. so the table can be.

```
    +----------+-------------+----------+
    | dog_id   | tail_length | owner_id |
    +----------+-------------+----------+
    | dog-id-1 | 1 cm        | owner-1  |
    | dog-id-2 | 2 cm        | owner-2  |
    | dog-id-3 | 3 cm        | owner-3  |
    | dog-id-3 | 3 cm        | owner-1  |
    | dog-id-3 | 3 cm        | owner-1  |
    +----------+-------------+----------+
```

But it is not possible as *dog_id* is a primary key and *owner_id* is unique in the table. A dog can possible be shared with 10000+ users.

Due to constraints of backward compatibility I cannot remove the primary and unique key constraints of the original table and I have to use mysql to do this. What would be the best strategy to achieve sharing?

Additional Constraint: I can only query through dog_id and not owner_id.

Comment: Why is the old table even relevant? What does "I can only query through dog_id and not owner_id" mean? Is there some problem with the obvious solution of a table with dog_id & owner_id, with (dog_id, owner_id) unique & FKs to Dogs & Owners?

Comment: *"I can only query through dog_id and not owner_id"*
Normally I get the dog_id as the input from the user, so I fetch the dog attributes and owner id from the table.

There is a primary key on dog_id and a unique key on owner_id. I really can't change that.

As Bill Karwin pointed out, this is a classic many to many relationship and is solved using a junction table, I will probably be using that.

Comment: If you cannot get rid of the Uniqueness constraint on `owner_id`, you cannot use this table.  Period.  Fullstop.

Comment: @Rick Yes, I'm following Bill Karwin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a many-to-many relationship.

- A dog can have many owners
- An individual owner can own many dogs

This is a common problem in relational database design. What you need for a many-to-many relationship is to define another table.

```
+----------+----------+
| dog_id   | owner_id |
+----------+----------+
| dog-id-1 | owner-1  |
| dog-id-2 | owner-2  |
| dog-id-3 | owner-3  |
| dog-id-3 | owner-1  |
| dog-id-3 | owner-1  |
+----------+----------+
```

> I can only query through dog_id and not owner_id

I don't understand why this is relevant. The data organization is about [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), not about how you will query the data.

The only alternative you have is to store multiple owner ids in one column of one row, which is not a valid design for a relational database. See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/20860)

Answer (score 0):

Create another table Owners and supply a Foreign Key to the table Dogs.

Comment: I can only query through dog_id and not owner_id, I have added this to the question now.